# Expanding Excel reports

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am not very experienced in using Excel spreadsheets, but have created one for a client and need help.  I set it up so all the columns are on one page, but would like the rows to be larger and extend to 2nd and even 3rd pages.  I tried enlarging the rows vertically, but still prints out on one sheet.

Comment: Can you post a link to a screenshot?  That would make it easier for people to understand the exact nature of the problem.  In general, though, you can control the pagination at View | Page Break Preview.  You will see page boundaries as dotted lines that you can drag where you want to control what is forced to pages.

Comment: For me, the Row height (vertical) seems to be fine and I am able to take multiple page print out with enlarged row height size. Ensure, the cells in the specific row has chosen "Wrap Text" from the 'Home' tab and row height is entered in numbers by right clicking the row > Row Height.

Answer (score 0):

If this is purely about physically printing the sheet then look at the print settings. Have you got it set up to print everything on a single page? Have you specified a print area? If you set it to fit all columns on one page the rows should break across pages. You may want to look at page setup too to repeat the header rows on each page.